# Minimal modular sum of subsets of $Z^n$

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, modular-arithmetic

I'm not quite sure how to frame this question, so I hope this is clear enough!

From a set of integers, $N$, a subset $R$ must be chosen, such that the residue of the sum of elements in $R$, modulo some value $m$ is minimised. What is the most efficient way to choose $R$, given there are $n$ elements in $N$, randomly distributed in $Z^+$, and $r$ elements must be chosen, where $r \ll n$.

Clearly the brute force approach is to take each possible $R$, add the elements and compute the residue. There will be $^nC_r=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ computations, which becomes impractical as $n$ gets large.

However I feel like this must be a problem that has been solved in a far more elegant and general way. It initially feels similar to various problems in combinatorics (travelling salesman, knapsack), but is more complicated because the total 'cost' of $R$ is not a linear combination of its elements.

And that's where my limited knowledge runs out. I can't find any literature or relevant SO questions, probably because I'm not using the right search terms.

Is what I've described part of a more general set of problems?

Here is an extension to the problem: instead of integers, the set $N$ contains $d$ dimensional vectors, and there is a vector $\textbf m$ which must be used for computing the cost. The aim is to minimise the cost given by:

$\sum_{i=1}^r \left(\left( \sum_{j=1}^d R_{ij} \right) \mod \textbf m_j \right)$

(i.e. the sum of the residues), where again, $r=|R|$. I think this is only harder because evaluating the cost function requires more operations...

Comment: There is no order relation like $<$ in the integers mod $m,$ so how are two of them compared? Maybe you mean to compare the least non-negative integer residues? If so include that...

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've updated the question - is this more clear?

Comment: Another question is about "randomly distributed in $Z^+$, since there isn't a uniform distribution on that set. However, since you're fixing the modulus $m,$ you could instead say you are choosing $n$ residues mod $m$ uniformly, as the values mod $m$ for the large set of size $n=|N|,$ after which you are to choose a subset of $N$ of size $r,$ in such a way as to get a minimal residue sum of the elements of $N.$ It would seem if the size of $m$ is large w.r.t. $m$ that it would be quite likely one could make the relevant residue sum zero, optimal by your definition.

Comment: Yes, good point (if you meant $m$ large w.r.t $r$). Assuming that this is not the case though, and if the elements in $N$ are taken from a subset of $Z^+$, e.g., {1,...100}, that 'escape route' disappears.